# How wolfram defines injectivity?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

I was looking for a fast way of getting which function is surjective and injective. So I tried to find such command in wolfram and surprisingly it says to me that $ln(x)$ is not injective. Link to proof: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ln%28x%29+is+injective%3F

The questions are:

**(1)** Why did Wolfram|Alpha say that it is not injective?

**(2)** How the injectivity is defined in Wolfram?

Comment: This is really weird (I would have expected this to be a problem with the domain, but WA has chosen precisely the domain it ought to in order to get an injective function).

Comment: I was expecting something like this too, but as we can see, Wolfram gets the domain rightly. That's why I asked it here.

Comment: I've reported it to them. Looks like a bug. Mathematica sheds no light on it either.

Comment: Looks like a bug, note: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log+is+injective+on+%280%2Cinfinity%29

Comment: It's still not fixed!

Comment: It seems that they finally fixed it.